# ServerManager.CommitChanges() caused exception on applicationHost.config

Tags: c#, iis, servermanager

When applying code like

```
            using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
            {
                var site = serverManager.Sites.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Name == siteName);
                // some logic to add sites, set application pool. 
                // But not creating new ServerManager instances.


                serverManager.CommitChanges();
            }
```

it would be some chances throw exceptions

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Filename: \\?\C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
Error: Cannot commit configuration changes because the file has changed on disk

at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Interop.IAppHostWritableAdminManager.CommitChanges()
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationManager.CommitChanges()
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.CommitChanges()
```

We have also tried to move away from `using` clause and use a singleton `ServerManager`, but the same issue is still there.

We are using Microsoft.Web.Administration 11.0.0 package.

Currently, we fixed it by catch the `serverManager.CommitChanges()` and apply `iisreset` in catch.

But it would be good if anybody knows the root cause/ how to fix it.

Comment: Is the IIS open? While running this code?

Comment: @viveknuna yes it is opened

Comment: Can you please close then try running your code. It might be locking

Comment: Yeah, but on the automated pipeline, IIS is closed and we also run into this issue. And we have resolved this issue by a kind of hack (iisreset), just want to know how to avoid this in code. Or the ServerManager class is just not robustly written?

Comment: You are not supposed to use that NuGet package in the first place, https://blog.lextudio.com/whats-microsoft-web-administration-and-the-horrible-facts-you-should-know-b82f2c974da6